# How to find all records with the same ID between two DataFrames?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two DataFrames with movie review data from two different platforms (id, title, review, etc). All rows about a particular movie need to be removed from one DataFrame if that movie has not been reviewed in the other DataFrame. Here's an example:

```
import pandas as pd 

data1 = [[1, 'Great movie!', 'Spiderman'], [1, 'Not my preference', 'Spiderman'], [2, 'Just average...', 'Captain America'], [4, 'Tolerable', 'Avengers']]

data2 = [[1, 'Did not think much of this', 'Spiderman'], [2, 'Great in my opinion!', 'Captain America'], [3, 'Could not finish', 'Batman Returns']]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns = ['id', 'review', 'movie title'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns = ['id', 'review', 'movie title'])

df1.insert(3, "isValid", pd.Series(df1.id.isin(df2.id).values.astype(bool)))
df1 = df1[df1.isValid != False]
```

I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way to do this?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: That's too broad of a question. Take a look at how to create a [mcve] to make it possible for people to reproduce your problem

Comment: Okay, will do. Thanks!

Comment: @rafaelc I've added an example and found a reasonable solution, but I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this as I have a few million records on either side? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have the information in df1 of `'isValid'` you can do this:

```
df1["isValid"] = df1.id.isin(df2.id)
new_df = df1.loc[df1.isValid == True]

   id             review      movie title  isValid
0   1       Great movie!        Spiderman     True
1   1  Not my preference        Spiderman     True
2   2    Just average...  Captain America     True
```

But if you don't care about `'isValid'` and just used it in your answer for selection you can simply do this:

```
new_df = df1.loc[df1.id.isin(df2.id)]

   id             review      movie title
0   1       Great movie!        Spiderman
1   1  Not my preference        Spiderman
2   2    Just average...  Captain America
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, this is the answer I was looking for. :)

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for `merge` function. This will drop all the ones not seen from both `df1` and `df2`.

```
df1.merge(df2,on=["id","movie title"])
Out: 
   id           review_x      movie title                    review_y
0   1       Great movie!        Spiderman  Did not think much of this
1   1  Not my preference        Spiderman  Did not think much of this
2   2    Just average...  Captain America        Great in my opinion!
```

your `df1` id the `id ,review_x ,movie title` and `df2` is `id, movie title review_y`

Comment: I have to keep the DataFrames seperate, so using merge doesn't solve the problem.